# incorrect variable value outside main()

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

i have this code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int testint;
NSString *teststring;

int Test()
{
    NSLog(@"%d",testint);
    NSLog(@"%@",teststring);
}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    testint = 5;
    NSString *teststring = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"test string"];
    Test();
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

in output i have:

5
(null)

why Test function doesn't see correct teststring value? What should I do, to have correct "test string" in output?

Answer (score 6):

You're shadowing a global variable with a local one.  If the intent is to use the global testString, you shouldn't re-declare it with "NSString*".

Comment: how should i declare global objects with "alloc init"?

Comment: Probably inside a dedicated initialize function, or main.  Just take the type off and it becomes an assignment instead of a declaration.  You could also consider not using global variables and passing the data in to the functions that need them.

Answer (score 2):

> in output i have:
>
> ```
> 5 (null)
> ```
>
> why Test function doesn't see correct teststring value?

Because you never assigned anything there. In `main`, you declared a local variable with the same name, and initialized that variable with the pointer to the NSString object you created.

> how should i declare global objects with "alloc init"?

You don't.

Declarations create variables (or sometimes types). The `NSString *teststring` lines (both of them) are declarations: One of a global variable, the other of a local variable.

`alloc` messages (and most other messages to classes) create objects.

Thus, this line:

```
NSString *teststring = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"test string"];
```

declared a local variable (`teststring`) *and* created a string object, and initialized the variable to hold the pointer to the string object.

(Note that “`initWithString:`” initializes the object, not the variable. The part from the `=` until the semicolon is the initializer for the variable.)

You meant to assign to the global variable, not declare a local variable. So, do that: Leave out the type specifier to turn the declaration into an assignment statement:

```
teststring = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"test string"];
```

By the way, you don't need to use `alloc` and `initWithString:` here. `@"test string"` is already an NSString object. And when you do `alloc` something, don't forget to release it (assuming you didn't turn on the GC).

Answer (score 1):

You have two different variables named `testint`. The one in `main()` is shadowing the global one.

Answer (score 1):

> how should i declare global objects with "alloc init"?

Strings are a special case.  You can do this:

```
NSString* foo = @"bar";
```